# Contact form not working

Tags: php, html, forms, email

i can't make this contact form work, not sure what it is, will much appreciate your         help. here is the code:

```
<?php
//Process Contact
if (isset ($_POST['send'])) {
//Variables
$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$message=$_POST['message'];

//Check all the inputs
if ($name!='' && $email!='' && $message!='') {
// then Html
$contenido = '<html><body>';
$contenido .= '<h2>Contact from</h2>';
$contenido .= '<p>Sent: '.  date("D M Y").'</p>';
$contenido .= '<p>Name: <strong>'.$name.'</strong>';
$contenido .= '<p>Email: <strong>'.$email.'</strong>';
$contenido .= '<p>Message: <strong>'.$message.'</strong>';
$contenido .= '<hr />';
$contenido .= '</body></html>';

// If the forms are full, it shows the message
mail ("mj@marijoing.com", "Mother-Well", $contenido, "From: $email\nContent-Type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit"); 
$flag='MessageSuccess';
$mensaje='<div class="MessageSuccess">Your message has been sent, we will contact you shortly .<br/><strong>Thank you!</strong> </div>';

} else {
//If there's a from to fill...  
$flag='err';
$mensaje='<div class="MessageError">All the information in the entry form are required.     Please, try again</div>';
}
}
?>

And the HTML:

<? echo $mensaje; /*Status form */ ?>
<? if ($flag!='MessageSuccess') { ?>
<form action="contact.php" method="post"> 
<input <? if (isset ($flag) && $_POST['name']=='') { echo 'class="MessageError"';}?> type="text" value="<? echo $_POST['name'];?>" maxlength="40" /><br />
<input <? if (isset ($flag) && $_POST['email']=='') { echo 'class="MessageError"';} ?>     type="text" value="<? echo $_POST['email'];?>" maxlength="40" /><br />               
<textarea <? if (isset ($flag) && $_POST['message']=='') { echo 'class="MessageError"';}     ?> name="message" rows="4"><? echo $_POST['message'];?></textarea><br />
<input type="submit" value="CONTACT US" name="send" />
</form>

<? } ?>

Hope somebody can help me, thanks in advance :)
```

Comment: What isn't working, does it give any error?... Don't just give the code and ask for help and say this isn't working, we're not suppose to debug your whole code for you.

Comment: Can you use `<? if` or do you always need `<?php if`?  There are several instances of that. Not a shortcut I am familiar with… What error messages do you get? What does "not working" mean to you?

Comment: Sorry Attis Barros, if you are going to be so meanfull don't bother to help me.. maybe i ask wrong.. but i can have a second chance? The problem is that the contcat form dont work, when i try to send and email the error message said: All the information in the entry form are required. Please, try again.. but i have entry all the code.

Comment: Maybe the error is in the form that calls this one. Can you do a `print_r($_POST);` to show all the values that are set when you call this script?

Answer (score 0):

This is by no means the only possible error, but you do

```
<? if ($flag!='MessageSuccess') { ?>
<form action="contact.php" method="post"> 
<input <? if (isset ($flag)
```

In other words, you are *assuming* the `$flag` variable exists in the outer loop, then test for its existence in the inner loop. That makes no sense.

Further I would recommend using

```
<?php
```

instead of

```
<?
```

at all times. Not sure if that makes a difference, but it's certainly more conventional.  See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/151694 for a description of short tags, and when they are OK to use (did you enable them in your build?)

Comment: Are you making progress? Did you try my suggestions? What do you get when you `print_r($_POST);`?

Comment: i make it work!.. i found out that parameter name="name" was missing   so now is working, thanks for your help!